# duda con instancia de objetos en java

Tags: java

Tengo una duda acerca de instanciar objetos en Java. Si tengo dos clases y una extiende a la otra, cuando hago una instancia de alguna de ella con:

```
A c = new B();
```

lo que hago con esto es instanciar la clase B pero con los atributos de la clase A?

Por ejemplo, con este código:

A.java

```
public class A {
    public void printValue(){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}
```

B.java

```
public class B extends A {
    public void printValue(){
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

Test.java

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        A b = new B();
        b.printValue();
    }
}
```

debiera recibir el String A como salida, ya que con A b = new B() estoy instanciando B con los atributos de la clase A? Sin embargo recibo "B".

Otro ejemplo más:

A.java

```
public class A {
public static void value(String y) {
System.out.println("A");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
A c = new B();
String x = "B";
c.value(x);
}
}
```

B.java

```
public class B extends A{
    public static void value(String x) {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

en este ejemplo sucede lo contrario. Instancio la clase B con A c = new B() paro siempre recibo como salida "A" que es el atributo de la clase A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saludos, virtual8870.

> lo que hago con esto es instanciar la clase B pero con los atributos
>   de la clase A?

Algo así, cuando extiendes una clase de otra, la clase que creas (en este caso `B`) es una ***clase hija***, que será un nuevo objeto que será similar a la ***clase padre*** (en este caso `A`). No solo tendrá los atributos de su padre, sino también sus métodos.

> debiera recibir el String A como salida, ya que con A b = new B()
>   estoy instanciando B con los atributos de la clase A? Sin embargo
>   recibo "B".

No, este comportamiento está bien. La razón por la cuál no recibes "A", es porque estás sobreescribiendo el método `printValue()` (que `B` heredó de `A`).

En `Java`, el sobreescribir un método que proviene de una ***clase padre*** se conoce como `@Override`. En español, esta palabra significa algo así como 'anular' o 'sobreponerse', y es precisamente eso lo que estás haciendo. Estás *anulando* el comportamiento original por uno nuevo y el nuevo comportamiento que le diste fue:

```
System.out.println("B");
```

Por eso es que recibes "B" como resultado.

Para obtener el resultado que esperas, debes utilizar `super.printValue();`

Esto permite utilizar o llamar al método original que hereda de su padre, sin anular o modificar su resultado.

Así que en resumen, la clase 'B' debería quedar así:

```
public class B extends A {

    @Override
    public void printValue() {
        super.printValue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Eso que estas asiendo se llama polimorfismo---> principi de sustitucion:

podemos almasenar un objeto de la supclase si el programa espera un objeto de la superclase.
Pero para poder entender esto ay que tener claro lo que es la Herencia y demas conseptos basicos de la POO

Cuando un intansia una clase (a extends b) a secombierte en la clase que hereda mas, osea a es la subclase y b la superclase entonses la subclase Hereda todos sus metodos parametros de los constructores que pueda tener la clase b y demas. Y ademas un metodo estatic solo puede  actuar sobre variables static osea variables de clase que no son copiadas por cada intancia o objeto sino que tiene una unica copia para cada uno de esas intancias por esta razon un metodo static solo podra invocarse poniendo el nombre de la clase delante de dicho metodo porque pertenese a la clase en la que fue declarada no a ninguna objeto.Ademas de que ay que respetar la encapsulacion por esto al declarar  un atributo de objeto se debe poner private delante de dicha variable ejemlo private int animal;.Ademas cuando Se hereda se debe aplicar la regla es un osea preguntarse si una subclse es una superclase eso que isiste no es adecuado se debe de partir de una clase principal como Animal y de esa Heredaran Perro,Gato y Mono entonses se puede desir que un Perro es un Animal un Gato es un Animal Y un Mono es un animal sin enbargo ninguno comparte las mismas caracteristicas para darle un caracteristica diferente a cada clase se usa los metodos abstractos o clases abstractas ya que al declarar un solo metodo abstracto la clase en la que es declarado tiene que ser abstracta igual que el metodo que difiere sutilmente de los interfases que asen casi lo mismo pero tienen una caracteristica  que lo asen diferente y es que pueden usar como una Herencia multiple  ya que una Interfas puede heredar de otra y una clase implementar una interfas y ademas Heredar los metodos de las dos Interfases mas los metodos y demas cosas que puedan contener  las demas superclases.

Comment: Hola Karel! Gracias por tu aporte, considera darle un poco de formato a tu respuesta, para mas información puedes revisar [answer].

Answer (score 0):

En el primer ejemplo, tienes métodos de instancia.
En el segundo son métodos de clase (static).

Para el primero no importa el tipo de la variable declarada ya que en tiempo de ejecución el método ejecutado es el instanciado.

Para el segundo solo importa la clase declarada ya que el método es de clase.